# Gitlab CI deploy AWS EC2

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

we have a lumen application we move the project to GitLab we wanna pull the project if all is ok.

We add the two scripts:

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
 - All or variables
stages:
  - test
  - production

testing:
  type: test
  image: php:7.1
  script:
    - echo "ok"

#Production stage
production:   
   stage: production   
   before_script: 
     - mkdir -p ~/.ssh     
     - echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa     
     - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa     
     - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'   
   script:     
      - bash .gitlab-deploy.sh   
   environment:     
      name: production     
      url: https://alpha.merci.network/
   when: manual
```

our deploy script ".gitlab-deploy.sh" looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Get servers list
set -f
string=$DEPLOY_SERVER
array=(${string//,/ })

#Iterate servers for deploy and pull last commit
for i in "${!array[@]}"do    
      echo "Deploy project on server ${array[i]}"    
      ssh ubuntu@${array[i]} "cd /var/www && git pull origin master"
done
```

We already add the configuration:

[image]

When we push changes to the repo/master we saw on the dashboard log the next error:

[image]

So what we are missing? Any advice?

Comment: That's probably not it but it's worth the shot, can you add a space before `do` in `for i in "${!array[@]}"do `

Comment: My error on the copy it has the space, still doesnt work D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just change the for to this for make it work:

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
  echo "Deploying information to EC2 and Gitlab"
  echo "Deploy project on server ${array[i]}"
  ssh ubuntu@${array[i]} "cd  /var/www/merci_deploy_api && git pull origin master"
done
```

Comment: i am getting "This job is stuck, because you don't have any active runners that can run this job. " error on pipline page, how i can fix it

Comment: whats your configuration?

Comment: I am using gitlab with yml based deployment. pipeline is created properly but how i can execute pipeline to deploy on AWS EC2. I have setup above configuration in yml file but when i try to execute pipeline manually it's show above error. can you please let me know how i can setup runner for AWS EC2 and execute pipeline.

Comment: That problem if i remember is when you use "tags", need to change that if you got it

Comment: i have removed tags but problem is AWS EC2 work with pem file, so how i can register runner with pem file. can you please let me know how i can register runner on runner server using pem file, my runner server is independent server and my gitlab server is also indepemend server.

Comment: You still need to use variables you need to set in there your ip/ec2 and your ssh key access.

Comment: I have already add variable and pemfile secret in gitalb variable section but problem is how pipeline execute, above yml code run when pipeline trigger, so my question is how i can trigger pipeline. I have try with manual trigger pipeline from gitlab panel but there show "This job is stuck, because you don't have any active runners that can run this job." error.

Comment: Did you restart the runner?

Comment: I have been getting connection time out message. Do we need to allow any special IPs to access SSH using the security groups?