# How to deploy code build to a EC2 instance from GitLab Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have been working on a React web app and I need to deploy it now. I have the codebase in GitLab and I'm using Gitlab pipeline to run the tests and create build and deploy. For deployment I need to deploy it to a EC2 instance. My pipeline runs well until creating the build. Now the problem is how to push that created build to the EC2 instance. Can someone help me in here. I tried in the following way. 
[Gitlab CI deploy AWS EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032256/gitlab-ci-deploy-aws-ec2)

It showed me connection time out message instead of connecting to ec2 instance. After that I allowed all IPs to access the instance with SSH using the security groups. Then it worked fine for me. But the problem is it's not secure to allow all IPs to access SSH. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: So you can create a git lab runner. Basically provision on ec2 instance and setup the runner in that. Now whitelist the IP address of that RUNNER. EVEN you can try to launch the runner in same vpc and whitelist the subnets so that only instances in that subnet can reach your ec2 instance

Comment: You can connect to the EC2 machine over ssh via secure-key. The command in to connect like "ssh -i secure-key ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx".